# MySql Procedure for randomly populating rows only populates one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a procedure that populates randomly records in a table.
But when i execute that procedure, the procedure inserts only one row.
CAN ANYONE HELP!

```
create procedure aa 

 ( @row INT
  )

as
begin
declare @numint as int
 declare @string as  VARCHAR(10)  
declare @length as INT
declare @code as  INT
declare @oid  as  uniqueidentifier

set @numint =0;

WHILE @numint <= @row 

BEGIN 
   SET @numint = @numint + 1; 

   set @oid = newid(); 

   SET @length = ROUND(10*RAND(),0);

   SET @string = ''; 

   WHILE @length > 0 BEGIN 

      SET @length = @length-1;

      SET @code = ROUND(10*RAND(),0) - 1; 

      IF @code BETWEEN 1 AND 26  
         SET @string = @string + CHAR(ASCII('a')+@code-1);
      ELSE
         SET @string = @string + ' '; 
   END 
end
   -- Ready for the record

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (

      @oid,

      @numint,

      ROUND(2000000*RAND()-1000000,2),

      CONVERT(DATETIME, ROUND(50000*RAND()-10000,2)),

      @string

   )
END

exec procedure '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is outside of the loop. Move it up to be inside the first loop and you should get the correct number of rows.